# Subprocess.Popen error

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

```
Proc = subprocess.Popen ([ 'FileName'])
```

The FileName is a variable which stores "**/home/USER/exec.sh &**", the program searches for the exec.sh file in the home folder and stores the path in FileName.I am unable to start this exec.sh process.It gives me the following error

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I initially used::

```
os.system(FileName)
```

It worked perfectly but didn't return the pid. Thus, I switched to Popen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just:

```
fileName = "/home/USER/exec.sh"
proc = subprocess.Popen(fileName)
pid = proc.pid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving this naive que!stion